# How to create Excel formula that adds a cell if it's negative or subtracts it if it's positive?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to create Excel formula that adds a cell if it's negative or subtracts it if it's positive?

I understand I can use simple forumlas like `=A37+D35` or `=A37+SUMIF(D35,"<0")` if I already know which direction the formula should go (adding or subtracting), but...

how do I get the formula to figure that out for me?

I want to say: *"If D35 is negative ADD it to A37, BUT if it's positive SUBTRACT it from A37"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple if statement.

```
=IF(D35<0,D35+A37,D35-A37)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but thank you!

Comment: @thepaperescape, If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the field negative and it will automatically flip the sign.

```
=A37-D35
```

If D35 is negative, the double negative turns to positive.

Comment: Read my question again. This is not helpful.

Comment: Can you add examples? I guess I'm not clear on what you are asking.

Comment: Viper941 answered this below. Here is what I was trying to accomplish: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T1u8fLH_c_uwv8AMrI1ew-QirPaSbTOFvpmnDQeOwEE. Add $1000 to Eva's side to see it in action.